# Can’t import ‘httpclient’ from ‘@angular/common/http’ after Angular upgraded from v4 to v5

Tags: angular, httpclient, angular-upgrade

I have a problem with Angular after I upgraded it from version 4 to version 5. I can’t use `httpclient` anymore.

Here are screenshots with the list of my npm packages and the contents of the `package.json` file:

[image: npm packages]

[image: package.json contents]

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you're using vs2017

do it like this

open **cmd** and type this `cd 'location_of_your_project'`

then type this

```
npm install @angular/common@5.0.0 @angular/compiler@5.0.0 @angular/compiler-cli@5.0.0 @angular/core@5.0.0 @angular/forms@5.0.0 @angular/http@5.0.0 @angular/platform-browser@5.0.0 @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@5.0.0 @angular/platform-server@5.0.0 @angular/router@5.0.0 @angular/animations@5.0.0 --save-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

In `app.module.ts` import `HttpClientModule` from `@angular/common/http` like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, HttpClientModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then in your `component` or `service` you can import `HttpClient` from `@angular/common/http' and use it by injection into construction.